# WPF No Events from Controls in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, focus, richtextbox

I am using WPF and have a Table inside a RichTextBox control. I need to get the background colour of the table cell to change it gets the focus. My problem is that I can't get the GotFocus or any other events to fire for the TableCell.

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
       <Table>
           <Table.Columns> 
              <TableColumn />
           </Table.Columns>
           <TableRowGroup>
               <TableRow>
                   <TableCell GotFocus="SelectionCell_GotFocus">
                       <Paragraph>1</Paragraph>
                   </TableCell>
               </TableRow>
           </TableRowGroup>
       </Table>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

The image below shows the table in the RichTextBox control. What I'd like to be able to do is change the background as the user moves between the table cells.

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/8151/wpftable.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/8151/wpftable.png)

Edit: After more investigation the issue is not confined to Table's in a RichTextBox, no control in a RichTextBox appears to be able to generate events. I placed a button into it and was not bale to get it to fire its Click event. It looks like the RichTextBox masks all events, hopefully there is a way to unmask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The half answer is to set the IsDocumentEnabled property on the RichTextBox to true. That allows controls within it to be enabled as per [Embedded UI Elements in RichTextBox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5372c48e-3040-4312-8263-59616e6728a8/). Unfortunately that still doesn't fire the event I need which is the GotFocus on a TableCell although it is possible to get the event to fire by putting a button in the cell and clicking on it. That bubbles the GotFocus event up the UI tree to the TableCell. I don't want a button in every cell though so time to look for an alternative solution.

```
<RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Table>
            <Table.Columns> 
                <TableColumn />
            </Table.Columns>
            <TableRowGroup>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell GotFocus="SelectionCell_GotFocus">
                        <BlockUIContainer>
                            <Canvas>
                                <Button Click="Button_Click">
                                    Click
                                </Button>
                            </Canvas>
                        </BlockUIContainer>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableRowGroup>
        </Table>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

*I did find the following (at: http://www.databaseforum.info/8/504107.aspx) TRIED AND IT WORKS:*

ContentElement, one of the base classes of Paragraph and incidentally the base class of just about everything that lives in a document defines the properties and events you are looking for.

In Code

```
void MyCode() 
{
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.MouseEnter += p_MouseEnter;
}

void p_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Paragraph p = (Paragraph)sender;
    p.Background = Brushes.Red;
}

**In Markup**

<Paragraph MouseEnter="p_MouseEnter" />

**You can also trigger on properties like IsMouseOver in styles**
```